# Lance Vintage 150cc Fuel Pump

Tags: scooter

I have a Lance Vintage 150cc that we haven't rode in about a year.  I just got it out and put a new battery, oil, and gas in it.  When I try to start it, it makes that initial starting noise but the engine just won't turn over.

I looked at the engine and discovered that fuel was in the line going **toward** the fuel pump but no fuel in the line going **away** from the fuel pump.

Do I just need a new fuel pump?  If so where can I get/order/find one?

Comment: Do yu mean that the engine doesn't turn over or that it doesn't want to fire?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is? It just won't start lol.

Comment: Turning over means it makes the cranking noises. (As you hold the starter, the engine is making some noise.)

So if it's not turning over (just a click and then nothing) it is different than turning over and never firing on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fuel pump is a good place to start. I *believe* this scooter doesn't actually use a fuel pump, but a fuel diaphragm. I found two versions on [this website](http://www.powersportsmax.com/index_parts.php/tID/3/vID/1080/gID/11/cPath/292_313_379) which should be for your scooter.